# Android, RelativeLayout and dynamically adding elements

Tags: android

I have an app where I would like to add a free version with ads, but I wanted to make minimal changes to my code.  So in my layout I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/adFrameLayout" android:background="@android:color/white">

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonGrp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/adFrameLayout" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:id="@+id/normalGameBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/normalGame"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/shareBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/shareButton"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/aiRadioGrp" android:layout_below="@id/buttonGrp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/normalAI" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
     ...
</RadioGroup>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/aiRadioGrp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/description" android:textSize="16dip"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

So what I want is that the FrameLayout (adFrameLayout) that is at the top I wanted it to show ads if it was the free version and if paid then size should stay at 0.

So in the base (pro) code I use Guice to inject an object that does extra processing in onCreate.  In the pro version the code does nothing, in the free version I am doing this:

```
@Override
public void accept(Activity activity) {
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.adFrameLayout);
    frame.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
    frame.invalidate();
}
```

This is just an example to make sure it would work, which it does not, the FrameLayout stays at a size of 0.  How can I get it to resize in the code dynamically?  Of course if I specify 20px in the xml it works fine, but I would guess that in the paid version me trying to set the size to 0 won't work either.  What am I doing wrong?

BTW I set the size right after I do the setContentView(R.id.main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugghh, it was something that dealt with AndroidAnnotations.  For some reason it doesn't pick up layout changes like that in the onCreate method and I had to put it in the postOnCreate method.  That may have been doc'ed somewhere, but I missed it.  carry on